# Parsing text from PDF file in application hosted in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pdf

I am working on uploading a PDF file (available in machine locally/in Google Drive), saving it and then parsing the text from it. This text will then be used in writing to a word doc.
These functionality are working in my locally hosted application. However, after I deployed it in Google App Engine, I am no more able to parse a PDF file.
How can I read a PDF file in a Java application hosted in Google App Engine.
In Tomcat parser -

```
new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(file,"r")); //allow to read and parse pdf
```

In GAE-

```
new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(file,"r")); //throwing access denied..
```

Comment: *"These functionality are working in my locally hosted application."* - How do you do it there? Probably you merely need a special, GAE specific version of your PDF library, like iTextG in case of iText.

Comment: Is that `PDFParser` class part of some third party library or is it your own code?

Comment: Using iText worked. Thanks a ton !

Comment: So you used iTextG in place of iText and it worked? Shall I make that an actual answer?

Comment: I used iText and that worked. Yes, please make this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs running in *Google App Engine* may not do everything that a program on a local work station can. E.g. there obviously is no normal GUI which can be a hindrance to code using AWT, even if only to create an image file or interpreting font information!

Thus, programs and libraries not developed with GAE in mind may fail when deployed to GAE.

Some libraries have special versions for use with GAE, e.g. for iText there is iTextG.

As there are similar restrictions on Android, switching to an Android version of one's library may also help.

---

As a bottom line, when developing for GAE you have to check whether your libraries are compatible with GAE. If they aren't, you have to switch, either to GAE (or Android) versions of them or other libraries altogether.